# How to send information to server about voip call decline in background iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, voip

How to send VOIP call decline information to server when the app is in background? When i am trying, i am getting network connection was lost.

Answer (score 0):

There is PUSH mechanism created for wake up application. But it requires support from VOIP server side.

https://docs.wonderpush.com/docs/android-push-notifications-quickstart

(or just google "android push"/"ios push")